# Updating two sql tables using one query in java

Tags: java, sql

I want to update two sql tables at once in java. I'm using SQLiteManager. Could someone please suggest a way of doing that?

Comment: This looks more like an SQL question

Comment: @ 1blustone ... May be. But I want to know how to do it in java.

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Executing both queries in one statement?

Comment: open a connection and run both updates in 1 transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the driver and connection to the database, you should be able to run most sql commands from java.  There is not a single sql statement that will update two tables at once but you can update each table in turn which will have the same effect.

See http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectSQLite.do for some examples.

For a table update, use

```
statement.execute(sql);
```

where sql is a string of the form

```
sql = "UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = newValue WHERE someOtherColumn=value";
```